# NSTextField Cursor changes only on the second mouseEntered

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

I am trying to make a NSTextField act like an hypertext since yesterday. I have almost reached my goal but I still have one strange bug.
I subclassed NSTextField to override mouseEntered: and mouseExited:. In those methods, I underline the text in the NSTextField and change the NSCursor to pointingHandCursor.

The strange thing is that the underlining pops up every time while the cursor changing seems to work only from the second mouseEntered:. It doesn't show up the first time.

It seems related to my subclass and not the environment because if I place two of those NSTextField in my view, both of them show the cursor only on the second time I place my mouse over it.

Here is the code I used in my subclass :

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        NSTrackingAreaOptions option = NSTrackingInVisibleRect | NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveInKeyWindow;
        NSTrackingArea * area = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:self.bounds options:option owner:self userInfo:nil];
        [self addTrackingArea:area];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    [self addCursorRect:self.bounds cursor:[NSCursor pointingHandCursor]];

    if (!self.undelineText)
    {
        NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:self.stringValue];
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [attrString length]);
        [attrString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:range];
        self.undelineText = attrString;
    }
    [self setAttributedStringValue:self.undelineText];
}

- (void) mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    if (!self.normalText)
    {
        NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:self.stringValue];
        self.normalText = attrString;
    }
    [self setAttributedStringValue:self.normalText];
}
```

I hope you'll be able to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting NSTrackingArea code into awakeOnNib function?
So it will look like this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
  NSTrackingAreaOptions option = NSTrackingInVisibleRect | NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveInKeyWindow;
  NSTrackingArea * area = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:self.bounds options:option owner:self userInfo:nil];
  [self addTrackingArea:area];
}
```